# Transpose and rearrange Dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transpose

I need some help to rearrange a dataframe. this is what the data looks like.

```
Year  item 1  item 2  item 3
2001  22      54      33
2002  77      54      33
2003  22      NaN     33
2004  22      54      NaN
```

The layout I want is:

```
Items   Year  Value
item 1  2001  22
item 1  2002  77
...
```

And so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) if not necessary remove `NaN`s:

```
df = df.melt('Year', var_name='Items', value_name='Value')
print (df)
    Year   Items  Value
0   2001  item 1   22.0
1   2002  item 1   77.0
2   2003  item 1   22.0
3   2004  item 1   22.0
4   2001  item 2   54.0
5   2002  item 2   54.0
6   2003  item 2    NaN
7   2004  item 2   54.0
8   2001  item 3   33.0
9   2002  item 3   33.0
10  2003  item 3   33.0
11  2004  item 3    NaN
```

For remove `NaN`s add [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.melt('Year', var_name='Items', value_name='Value').dropna(subset=['Value'])
print (df)
    Year   Items  Value
0   2001  item 1   22.0
1   2002  item 1   77.0
2   2003  item 1   22.0
3   2004  item 1   22.0
4   2001  item 2   54.0
5   2002  item 2   54.0
7   2004  item 2   54.0
8   2001  item 3   33.0
9   2002  item 3   33.0
10  2003  item 3   33.0
```

For a bit different ordering with removing `NaN`s is possible use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Year').stack().rename_axis(['Year','Items']).reset_index(name='Value')
print (df)
   Year   Items  Value
0  2001  item 1   22.0
1  2001  item 2   54.0
2  2001  item 3   33.0
3  2002  item 1   77.0
4  2002  item 2   54.0
5  2002  item 3   33.0
6  2003  item 1   22.0
7  2003  item 3   33.0
8  2004  item 1   22.0
9  2004  item 2   54.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way of doing it. Maybe using Transform or crosstab?

Comment: @SANM2009 - I think `crosstab` or `pivot` is for reverse process - from my output create your input.

Answer (score 0):

Using comprehensions and `pd.DataFrame.itertuples`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[y, i, v]
     for y, *vals in df.itertuples(index=False)
     for i, v in zip(df.columns[1:], vals)
     if pd.notnull(v)],
    columns=['Year', 'Item', 'Value']
)

   Year    Item  Value
0  2001  item 1   22.0
1  2001  item 2   54.0
2  2001  item 3   33.0
3  2002  item 1   77.0
4  2002  item 2   54.0
5  2002  item 3   33.0
6  2003  item 1   22.0
7  2003  item 3   33.0
8  2004  item 1   22.0
9  2004  item 2   54.0
```